# How to show custom error message in a Toast from Handler?

Tags: android, dialog, handler, toast

I've created a custom handler that will take care of dismissing dialogs, showing dialogs and showing (custom) error messages. However, I'm stuck with the custom error message part. How do I post a message with custom message & how to parse it in the handleMessage?

Now I'm doing:

`handler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(handler, HANDLER_MESSAGE_ERROR));`

I've read about bundle, but didn't get it working. Preferably (to keep the code neat), I'd like to do something like this:

`handler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(handler, HANDLER_MESSAGE_ERROR, "Custom error message"));`

and for error dialog:

`handler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(handler, HANDLER_MESSAGE_DIALOG, "Custom title", "Custom error message"));`

Here's the handler code that I'm using right now:

```
public class MyHandler extends Handler {
    private Activity mContext;

    public MyHandler(Activity activity) {
        mContext = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case MyActivity.HANDLER_MESSAGE_ERROR:
            try {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "_This should be a custom error message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used handler to pass different messges. This code will work for you.

Pass only simple message:

```
Message msg = new Message();
msg.what = HANDLER_MESSAGE_ERROR;
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("message", "Custom error message");
msg.setData(b);
handler.sendMessage(msg);
```

Pass title and message:

```
Message msg = new Message();
msg.what = HANDLER_MESSAGE_DIALOG;
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("title", "Custom title");
b.putString("message", "Custom error message");
msg.setData(b);
handler.sendMessage(msg);
```

You will get the bundle in your method in the following way

```
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    //Get bundle
    Bundle b = msg.getData();
    String title,messag;
    switch (msg.what) {
    case MyActivity.HANDLER_MESSAGE_ERROR:
        try {
             message = b.getString("message");
             //show toast here
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        break;
    case MyActivity.HANDLER_MESSAGE_DIALOG:
        try {
             title = b.getString("title");
             message = b.getString("message");
             //show toast here
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Message object can store key value pairs like this:

```
final Message msg = new Message();
final Bundle data = new Bundle();
data.putString(ERROR, "error message");
msg.setData(data);
```

In the Handler extract the data from the bundle:

```
final String e = m.getData().getString(ERROR);
```